# Decoding array of hexadecimal bytes to a specific codepage brings a wrong result when encoding afterwards

Tags: java, string, encoding, character-encoding, charset

I created a simple app which looks like this:

```
    String stringValue = new String(new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x25 }, "273");
    byte[] valueEncoded = Arrays.copyOfRange(stringValue.getBytes("273"), 0, 4);
    int finalResult = ByteBuffer.wrap(valueEncoded).getInt();
    
    System.out.println("Result: "+finalResult);
```

I expect the result to be 37, however the result is 21. How come? Am I missing something? Or is my method not the way it is supposed to be and therefore this error pops up?

I tried many other numbers and all seem to work fine...
As you can see I am using codepage 273 (IBM).

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like linefeed 0x25 got mapped to newline 0x15.

I assume that it went like this:

bytes to string:  EBCDIC 0x25 -> UTF-16 0x000A

string to bytes:  UTF-16 0x000A -> EBCDIC 0x15.

Why that's preferred, I can't guess.  Well, actually I can guess (but it's only a guess).  0x000A is the standard line terminator on many systems, but it's generally output as "move to beginning of next line". Converting to IBM 273 is 'probably' because the text is destined for output on a device that uses that code page, and perhaps such devices want NL rather than LF for starting a new line.

---

Hypothesis validated:

```
 class D {
   public static void main(String... a) throws Exception {
       String lf = "\n";
       byte[] b = lf.getBytes("273");
       System.out.println((int)b[0]);
   }
}
```

Output is 21.

Comment: But is there any way to avoid such behavior ? I mean how can you make sure to decode/ encode integers without having to worry about such weird behavior?

Comment: Treat byte arrays as byte arrays and not as strings of text.  I take it that what you're actually doing is to convert a 4-byte integer in big-endian order into a Java int value?  Then why convert to text and back?

Comment: To be frank I don´t know why this text converting (and back) happens, it is some old code which I now have to take care of :) Ok I will try to implement your suggestion and see what happens.

Comment: The goal is to take an integer value, convert it to IBM273 and persist it so that the IBM machine can read (and understand) what you have persisted. Can you give an example on this? I did the following but its corrupt: byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(37).array();  ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
  CharBuffer data = utf8charset.decode(inputBuffer);
  
  ByteBuffer outputBuffer = ibm273.encode(data);
  int BufferResult = outputBuffer.getInt();

Comment: Ah, legacy code doing weird things. Sadly, I am familiar with that concept.  But I'm stuck with not really getting what you mean by converting an int value to some code page.  Either it's an integer or it's some text.  The value 37 has to remain 37 (right?) regardless of any code page. Is the fundamental issue that some lower-level I/O mechanism is treating the data as a string, rather than as bytes, when it's writing to a file?

Comment: Yes, the value 37 has to remain 37, but in order to make the IBM machine read this number correctly it has to be converted to a specific codepage (in my case IBM273)? What we currently do is the initial code snippet, at the end we do some formatting and persist to DB2, from this DB the IBM machine reads the code. The problem is that now my initial String / value "37" gets persisted as "21". My snippet is an example what happens, in the app itself we use a getBytes method to create a byte array. How to make sure now that I persist in the DB the exact value which comes from my Java app ?

Comment: Is this integer in a column by itself?  What is the data type of the column?  (Warning, I don't know DB2)

Comment: So the full story is: Our Springboot app gets called via Post/Get method and the request consists properties which get mapped to Java data type String. Then we do the part which I have shown. Basically we get the bytes of this String encoding via IBM273 charset, format it ("%" + length + "." + length + "s") and for the integers get the int via ByteBuffer.wrap(valueEncoded).getInt() . Then we concat all converted results / properties into a VARCHAR column in DB2 and persist it. Then the IBM machine read it in this IBM273 encoding. Not so smart / pretty solution but hey, I didn´t invent it :)

Comment: It seems like you want two mappings from String to byte[] -- to IBM 273 to extract the text parts, and to ASCII to exact the integer parts.

Comment: But isn´t the byte[] (IBM273) erroneous (see my initial code snippet)? Can you give an example on how to accomplish what you have suggested?

Comment: Also I have to mention that we expect this property to always be a number / integer.